# Php - Multiple Pages Same Url Different Ids?

Tags: php

I've been working on a project for which i want to create a page leading to different pages but i want to use same URL i have created all the pages but now i am stuck...
the Thing i want is.
i have pages ****

> index324.php , index34.php , index378.php , index345.php ,
>   index365.php , index334.php

---

What i want is to use a url -

> **`index.php`**?product_id=21
>   **`index.php`**?product_id=23

Something Like Shown Above.

Comment: generally when developers rewrite urls, they actually hide `$_GET` indexes, also `.php` extension

Answer (score 0):

On your `index.php`, check if `$_GET['product_id']` is set. If it is, use it to retrieve the desired ID which in turn you will use for checking against a database/file/whatever.

```
if (isset($_GET['product_id']))
    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
```

Of course, you'll want to do some validation on the fetched ID to be sure it won't harm anything in your system since it can be altered by anyone issuing a GET request to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have product detail pages for each product like: `product1.php`, `product2.php` etc ... You can include your desired file in `index.php` by passing `GET` parameter. e.g. (index.php?product_id=21) **:**

```
if(isset($_GET['product_id'])){
    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
    include('product' .$product_id. '.php');
}
else{
    // product_id is not set ... 
    // do more stuff...
}
```